# what's the difference between $('.p') and $('p') jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, web, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery, when I select some class from HTML, I can do it by `$('.p')` or `$('p')`. I'm confused, is there a difference?

Comment: [**Basic** CSS selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-css-selectors/).

Answer (score 5):

These are basically CSS selectors. Can be used in jQuery as it is.

1. `$('.p')` is [**class selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). It will select all the elements that are having class `p`.

   > In an HTML document, CSS class selectors match an element based on the contents of the element's class attribute. The class attribute is defined as a space-separated list of items, and one of those items must match exactly the class name given in the selector.

Example:

```
<a class="p">...</a>
<div class="p anotherClass">...</div>
<span class="firstClass p">...</span>
<p class="p">...</p>
```

2. `$('p')` is [**element/tag/type selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors). It will select all the `p`(paragraph) elements.

   > CSS type selectors match elements by node name. Used alone, therefore, a type selector for a particular node name selects all elements of that type — that is, with that node name — in the document.

Example:

```
<p>...</p>
<p class="anyClass">...</p>
<p id="anyId">...</p>
```

3. Also, there is an [**id selector**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors). `$('#p')` will select element having id of `p`.

   > In an HTML document, CSS ID selectors match an element based on the contents of that element's ID attribute, which must match exactly the value given in the selector.

Example:

```
<anyEl id="p">...</anyEl>
```

[MDN Selectors Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Answer (score 4):

`$('.p')` selects an element with a class that has that name:

```
<div class='p'>
```

So anything that has the `class='p'` will be selected:

```
<b class='p'></b>
<div class='p'></div>
<table class='p'></table>
```

`$('p')` selects all paragraph elements:

```
<p></p>
```

`$('#p')` selects an element with an id of `p`:

```
<div id='p'>
```

Similarly `$('#p')` selects an element with a id that has that name:

Answer (score 0):

`$('.p')` - this usually refers to class (i.e which you would have included under `<style> </style>` tag)

`$('p')` - is elemental, which by default applies for all Paragraph i.e (`<p> </p>`)

Comment: The `class` does not have to have a style define -- that is optional

Answer (score 0):

$('.p')  is a class selector which will search for a class  p
whereas $('p') is a selector for all paragraph in your html page .

for selectors u can refer this link to get all information regarding ids and classes .

Heres the link:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp